# Codeigniter: if statement is not working

Tags: php, codeigniter

I need to edit a profile in my website but i'm having a issue whenever i click on edit option. it redirects me to the login form which is in else statement, which means my if statement is not working and i don't know why.

my model code is working perfectly fine that's why i'm only uploading controllers code

Controller

```
function editprofileoverseas()

    {
        if($this->session->userdata('is_logged_in') == true)
        {
            $this->load->model('overseasmember_model');
            $this->load->model('wings_model');
            error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_WARNING); 
        $this->load->helper('registration');
        $this->data['title'] = "Register Member";
        $checked_wings = $this->input->post('wings');



        $this->form_validation->set_rules('firstname', 'Name', 'required');
        //$this->form_validation->set_rules('lastname', 'Last Name', 'required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('mobile', 'Mobile', 'required');
        /* changes address */
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('mailingaddress', 'Mailing Address', 'required');
                 $this->form_validation->set_rules('relation', 'Relation', 'required');
        /* changes address */

        $uploaddir = './profile_pics/';
        $session_id = $this->session->userdata('id');
        // changes
            $cn = $this->input->post('hidden3');
        $sessiondata101 = $this->session->all_userdata();
    if($this->session->userdata('membershipno') == null && $this->session->userdata('birth_date') == null && $this->session->userdata('created') == '')
        {

            if($cn == "<span class='status-not-available'>CNIC already registered.</span>")
            {
                $this->form_validation->set_rules('cnic', 'CNIC', 'matches[confirmcnic]|is_unique[free_members.cnic]|is_unique[domestic_members.cnic]|is_unique[overseas_members.cnic]');
            }
            elseif($cn == "<span class='status-not-available'>Enter correct CNIC format.</span>")
            {
                $this->form_validation->set_rules('cnic', 'CNIC', 'matches[confirmcnic]|regex_match[/\d{5}\-\d{7}-\d{1}\]');
            }
            elseif($cn == "<span class='status-not-available'>CNIC is required.</span>")
            {
                $this->form_validation->set_rules('cnic', 'CNIC', 'required|matches[confirmcnic]');
            }
            else
            {
                $this->form_validation->set_rules('cnic', 'CNIC');
            }
            //$this->form_validation->set_rules('cnic', 'CNIC', 'required|matches[confirmcnic]|is_unique[free_members.cnic]|is_unique[domestic_members.cnic]|is_unique[overseas_members.cnic]');
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('confirmcnic', 'CNIC Confirmation', 'required');
        }
        // changes
        if ($this->form_validation->run() == true)
        {
            // changes
                if($this->session->userdata('membershipno') == null && $this->session->userdata('birth_date') == null && $this->session->userdata('created') == '')
            {
                $data = array(

                    'first_name'    => preg_replace('/\s+/', ' ', $this->input->post('firstname')),

                    'dob'           => $this->input->post('dob'),
                    'mobile'        => $this->input->post('mobile'),
                    'phone'         => $this->input->post('phone'),
                    'country'       => $this->input->post('hidden20'),
                    'province'      => $this->input->post('hidden21'),
                    'city'          => $this->input->post('hidden31'),
                    'continent'     => $this->input->post('hidden32'),
                    'cnic' => $this->input->post('cnic'),
                    'membershipno' => $this->input->post('cnic'),
                    'created'       => date('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
                    /* changes address */
                    'mailingaddress' => $this->input->post('mailingaddress'),
                                        'relation' => $this->input->post('relation'),
                    /* changes address */
                );
            }
            else{
            $data = array(

                'first_name'    => preg_replace('/\s+/', ' ', $this->input->post('firstname')),
                            'dob'           => $this->input->post('dob'),
                'mobile'        => $this->input->post('mobile'),
                'phone'         => $this->input->post('phone'),
                'country'       => $this->input->post('hidden20'),
                'province'      => $this->input->post('hiddenprovince'),
                'city'          => $this->input->post('hidden31'),
                'continent'     => $this->input->post('hidden32'),

                    'mailingaddress' => $this->input->post('mailingaddress'),
                                'relation' => $this->input->post('relation'),

            );
        }
        // changes
        }
        if ($this->form_validation->run() == true)
        { 
            $sessiondata10 = $this->session->all_userdata();
                $data['id'] = $sessiondata10['id'];
                $sessiondata10['first_name'] = $data['first_name'];

                $sessiondata10['birth_date'] = $data['dob'];

                $sessiondata10['mobile'] = $data['mobile'];
                $sessiondata10['phone'] = $data['phone'];
                $sessiondata10['country'] = $data['country'];
                $sessiondata10['province'] = $data['province'];
                $sessiondata10['city'] = $data['city'];
                $sessiondata10['continent'] = $data['continent'];
                /* changes address */
                $sessiondata10['mailingaddress'] = $data['mailingaddress'];
                                $sessiondata10['relation'] = $data['relation'];
                /* changes address */
                // changes
    if($this->session->userdata('membershipno') == null && $this->session->userdata('birth_date') == null && $this->session->userdata('created') == '')
                {
                    $sessiondata10['cnic'] = $data['cnic'];
                }
                // changes
                if($checked_wings > 0 && $sessiondata10['wingid'] != null){
                $data3 = array();
                foreach($_POST['check_list2'] as $item1){
                    if($item1 == "Commerce & Trade")
                        $data3['Commerce_Trade'] = 1;
                    if($item1 == "Other")
                        $data3['Other'] = $this->input->post('otherfield');
                    if($item1 == "Industry")
                        $data3['Industry'] = 1;
                    if($item1 == "Lawyer")
                        $data3['Lawyer'] = 1;
                    if($item1 == "Doctor")
                        $data3['Doctor'] = 1;
                    if($item1 == "Minorities")
                        $data3['Minorities'] = 1;
                    if($item1 == "Women_Development")
                        $data3['Women'] = 1;
                    if($item1 == "Functionary")
                        $data3['Functionary'] = 1;
                }

                $this->wings_model->updateMember($data3,$sessiondata10['wingid']);

            }
            elseif($checked_wings > 0 && $sessiondata10['wingid'] == null){
                $data3 = array(
                'memberid' => $sessiondata10['id'],
                );
                foreach($_POST['check_list2'] as $item1){
                    if($item1 == "Commerce & Trade")
                        $data3['Commerce_Trade'] = 1;
                    if($item1 == "Other")
                        $data3['Other'] = $this->input->post('otherfield');
                    if($item1 == "Industry")
                        $data3['Industry'] = 1;
                    if($item1 == "Lawyer")
                        $data3['Lawyer'] = 1;
                    if($item1 == "Doctor")
                        $data3['Doctor'] = 1;
                    if($item1 == "Minorities")
                        $data3['Minorities'] = 1;
                    if($item1 == "Women_Development")
                        $data3['Women'] = 1;
                    if($item1 == "Functionary")
                        $data3['Functionary'] = 1;
                }

                $id3 = $this->wings_model->addMemberWing($data3);
                $data['wingid'] = $id3;
                $sessiondata10['wingid'] = $data['wingid'];
            }
                $uploadfile = $uploaddir . basename($_FILES['myFile']['name']);

                if(basename($_FILES['myFile']['name']) != NULL || basename($_FILES['myFile']['name'] != ''))
                {
                    if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['myFile']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile)){ 

                        $data['pic_path'] = $uploadfile;
                        $sessiondata10['pic_path'] = $uploadfile;

                    }else{
                        //echo "Possible file upload attack!\n";
                    }
                }
                else
                    $data['pic_path'] = $sessiondata10['pic_path'];
                $this->overseasmember_model->updateMember($data,$session_id);
                $data['is_logged_in'] = true;

                $this->load->view('overseasmemberarea',$sessiondata10);
                return;
        }
        else
        { 
            // changes
            $sessiondata1 = $this->session->all_userdata();

            $this->data['message'] = (validation_errors() ? validation_errors() : ($this->session->flashdata('message')));

            $this->data['first_name'] = array(
                'name'  => 'firstname',
                'id'    => 'firstname',
                'type'  => 'text',
                'class' => 'input-xlarge',
                'onBlur' => 'checkAvailability2()',
                'placeholder' => "",
                'size'      =>  32,
                'maxlength' =>  128,                
                'value' => $this->form_validation->set_value('first_name'),
            );


            $this->data['relation'] = array(
                'name'  => 'relation',
                'id'    => 'relation',
                'type'  => 'text',
                'class' => 'input-xlarge',
                //'onBlur' => 'checkAvailability4()',
                'placeholder' => "",
                'size'      =>  32,
                'maxlength' =>  128,                
                'value' => $this->form_validation->set_value('relation'),
            );

            $this->data['dob'] = array(
                'name'  => 'dob',
                'id'    => 'dob',
                'type'  => 'text',
                'class' => 'input-xlarge',
                'onBlur' => 'checkDOB()',
                'placeholder' => "DD-MM-YYYY",
                'size'      =>  32,
                'maxlength' =>  128,                
                'value' => $this->form_validation->set_value('dob'),
            );
            $this->data['mobile'] = array(
                'name'  => 'mobile',
                'id'    => 'mobile',
                'type'  => 'text',
                'class' => 'input-xlarge',
                'onBlur' => 'checkMobile()',
                'placeholder' => "03012345678",
                'size'      =>  32,
                'maxlength' =>  128,                
                'value' => $this->form_validation->set_value('mobile'),
            );
            $this->data['phone'] = array(
                'name'  => 'phone',
                'id'    => 'phone',
                'type'  => 'tel',
                'class' => 'input-xlarge',

                'placeholder' => "",
                'size'      =>  32,
                'maxlength' =>  128,                
                'value' => $this->form_validation->set_value('phone'),
            );

            /* changes address*/
            $this->data['mailingaddress'] = array(
                'name'  => 'mailingaddress',
                'id'    => 'mailingaddress',
                'type'  => 'text',
                //'class' => 'input-xlarge',
                //'onBlur' => 'checkPs()',
                'placeholder' => "",
                'cols'      =>  50,
                'rows'  =>  4,
                'value' => $this->form_validation->set_value('mailingaddress'),
            );
            /* changes address*/


            /* changes */
            $this->data['cnic'] = array(
                'name'  => 'cnic',
                'id'    => 'cnic',
                'type'  => 'text',
                'class' => 'input-xlarge',
                'onBlur' => 'checkAvailability3()',
                'placeholder' => "XXXXX-XXXXXXX-X",
                'size'      =>  32,
                'maxlength' =>  128,
                'value' => $this->form_validation->set_value('cnic'),
            );
            $this->data['confirmcnic'] = array(
                'name'  => 'confirmcnic',
                'id'    => 'confirmcnic',
                'type'  => 'text',
                'class' => 'input-xlarge',
                'onBlur' => 'checkAvailability3()',

                'placeholder' => "XXXXX-XXXXXXX-X",
                'size'      =>  32,
                'maxlength' =>  128,
                'value' => $this->form_validation->set_value('confirmcnic'),
            );

            $sessiondata1['cnic'] = $this->data['cnic'];
            $sessiondata1['confirmcnic'] = $this->data['confirmcnic'];




            $sessiondata1['message'] = $this->data['message'];
            $this->load->view('edit_profileoverseas',$sessiondata1);
        }
    }
    else
            $this->index();
    }
```

Comment: before the if statement add this `var_dump($this->session->userdata('is_logged_in'));` what do you see ? and plz format the code

Comment: @FastSnail sir seen nothing after adding that line of code!!! and sir what do you mean by format the code? i have uploaded it in formatted order i guess

Comment: you should see something even if it's empty

Comment: @FastSnail now i sees it its showing bool(false)

Comment: when you set sesstion try `$this->session->set_userdata('is_logged_in',true);`

Comment: @FastSnail nothing happened sir!!

Comment: Well it can only mean that you are never setting that value to true. So I would be checking your code where you set that value.

Comment: @TimBrownlaw so sir any suggestions for me to resolve the issue?

Comment: Yes I had made a suggestion above, check the code where you set your session values. Unless you provide the code that is all I can suggest. Where does is_logged_in get set in the session?

Comment: @TimBrownlaw i have set is_logged_in is my validate credentials function! and sir i tried your suggestion but it didn't worked out!! if you say i can provide you more code sir!!